# VBA Help: Macro to create new rows and populate data from existing rows

Tags: vba, excel

Below is a link for a file of sample raw data -> the desired output http://www.datafilehost.com/d/3e0c23fb

There is a set of columns unique to a user "John" and "Jim" and then a set of four columns with unique information for each ad they see. So, if they see two ads, 8 additional columns. If they see three, 12, and so on.

What I'd like a macro to do is determine how many sets of four exist per person, create new rows, and duplicate the person's info (e.g. 3 "John" rows) and put only one set of the 4 Ad columns on each.

The sample data should make it very clear.

All best practices and code tidbits welcomed.

Comment: have you tried something already? If yes, show us your attempts, please

Comment: It has been a work in progress today, I have been trying to do this piece by piece (adding rows, copying ranges) but I am always completely outdone by the experts on this site with regards to best practices of setup and moving forward so I was seeking an approach suggestion moreso than a finished piece of work

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to give each person their own row on a separate tab with a unique ID and all additional information alongside:

```
PersonID Name Age etc.
1        John 42  foo
2        Jim  17  bar
```

Then, instead of duplicating John's information on every row of your ad info tab, just put the PersonID. That'll make your life easier when it comes to updating person information. It's also [good practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Secondly, I suggest you have a function with both `dim srcCell as Range` and `dim targetCell as Range`. That way you can move through the source data (with `set srcCell = srcCell.Offset(0, 1)`) and still keep track of where the data is supposed to be pasted to.

Once the `srcCell` and `targetCell` are in the right places, you can do `targetCell.Value = srcCell.value` to easily copy the value over.

For example:

```
Set srcCell = Worksheets("foo").Range("A1")
Set targetCell = Worksheets("bar").Range("A1")

Do While srcCell <> ""
  for i = 1 to 4
    targetCell.Value = srcCell.Value ' Copy the value across
    set srcCell = srcCell.Offset(0, 1) ' Move srcCell along one
    set targetCell = targetCell.Offset(0, 1) ' Move targetCell along one
  next i
  ' Move targetCell to the start of the next row. targetCell.Parent is
  ' the WorkSheet that targetCell is on.
  set targetCell = targetCell.Parent.Cells(targetCell.Row + 1, 1)
  set srcCell = srcCell.Offset(0, 1)
Loop

' Now here, you'll have to move srcCell back to the start of the next row
' and do the whole thing again for the next row!
```

That should get you started.